# Combine arrays into objects depending on elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, sorting, foreach

I have two arrays, Array 1 containing the sections, and Array 2 containing the objects, the goal is to insert the objects from Array 2 inside the objects into Array1 depending on the type (Sides or Sauces), for example: Each object from Array 2 containing the element `type:Sauces` should be set in an array inside the object of Array 1 with `type:Sauces` and so on. I tried by using the `forEach` function but since I'm relatively new to JavaScript I don't know how to proceed

**Array 1 (Sections)**

```
Array [
  Object {
    "required": false,
    "type": "Sides",
  },
  Object {
    "required": true,
    "type": "Sauces",
  },
]
```

**Array 2 (List of Objects)**

```
Array [
  Object {
    "id": 2.01,
    "price": "1",
    "title": "Hot Sauce",   
    "type": "Sauces",       
  },
  Object {
    "id": 2.02,
    "price": 1,
    "title": "Medium Sauce",
    "type": "Sauces",       
  },
  Object {
    "id": 1.01,
    "price": 1,
    "title": "Ranch",
    "type": "Sides",
  },
  Object {
    "id": 1.02,
    "price": 1,
    "title": "Blue Cheese",
    "type": "Sides",
  },
]
```

this is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
Array [
      Object {
        "required": false,
        "type": "Sides",
        "data": [
                 Object {
                   "id": 1.01,
                   "price": 1,
                   "title": "Ranch",
                   "type": "Sides",
                 },
                 Object {
                   "id": 1.02,
                   "price": 1,
                   "title": "Blue Cheese",
                   "type": "Sides",
                 },
                ]
      },
      Object {
        "required": true,
        "type": "Sauces",
        "data":[
                 Object {
                  "id": 2.01,
                  "price": "1",
                  "title": "Hot Sauce",   
                  "type": "Sauces",       
                 },
                 Object {
                  "id": 2.02,
                  "price": 1,
                  "title": "Medium Sauce",
                  "type": "Sauces",       
                 },
               ]
      },
    ]
```

Comment: please add the data in literal notation. what is the wanted result? what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work for you:

```
arr1.forEach((a,i) => {
    a["data"] = arr2.filter(b => b.type == a.type);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I name Array1 = categories
I name Array2 = elements
You need to map on each.

```
 const test = categories.map((cat) => {
          elements.map((el) => {
            if (el.type === cat.type) {
              cat.elements.push(el);
            }
            return el;
          });
          return cat;
        });
    console.log(test);
```

Comment: thanks for your response, I tried to run your solution and it gives me back the error: `[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'cat.sides.push')]`

Comment: It because I add a property 'elements' with value [] on Array 1  to stock your elements